# Using ninject, can I create a binding to a class that has an attribute and satisfies a predicate?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a base class for classes that can act as plugins to a central system. I want to allow these plugins to be defined in third-party assemblies. The central system instantiates the plugins based on some command line arguments.

To achieve this, I have created an attribute that these classes can be decorated with, something like:

```
[ArgName("some-module")]
```

And at the point of their initialization, I'm using a piece of code that reflects on all the loaded types, trying to find the one that has the attribute and the proper parameter:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
         .SingleOrDefault(x => /* check for attribute and predicate */);
```

This works fine.

But I feel like I'm re-inventing something that a DI framework might have on its own. So, since I'm already using Ninject for some other dependencies in my project, I was wondering: is there any way I can delegate this responsibility to Ninject as well, instead of writing custom reflection code?

In other words, does Ninject already have something I've missed that does roughly the following:

```
kernel.Bind<ModuleBase>()
      .ToTypesThatHaveThisAttribute<ArgName>()
      .With(x => x.Name == userProvidedCommandlineArgument);
```

Of course, I know I can create the above extension methods for `BindingToSyntax<T>` and make the syntax nicer where it's used. But I'd like to banish the reflection code altogether, if Ninject has this functionality built-in.

Comment: Have a look at the Ninject.Extensions.Conventions library, it has a lot of extra features, especially for such "batch" binding scenarios. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions

Answer (score 2):

Using `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` you can achieve something like this (not tested).

```
string arg = null;
Kernel.Bind(x =>
{
    x.FromThisAssembly()
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ArgNameAttribute));
            if (attributes.Length == 0) return false;
            var attribute = attributes[0];
            return attribute.ArgName == arg;
        })
        .BindSelection((type, interfaces) => new[] {typeof(PluginBase)});
});
```

But to be honest, it's almost the same amount of code comparing to manual type selection and binding with Reflection, similar to what you wrote. I mean something like this.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => {
         var attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ArgNameAttribute));
         if (attributes.Length == 0) return false;
         var attribute = attributes[0];
         return attribute.ArgName == arg;
    })
    .Select(x => Kernel.Bind<PluginBase>().To(x))...
```

I would probably do it without the `Conventions` extension, unless you find it useful in other ways.

Note that neither of these codes are tested, and I ment them only for example.

Comment: This is essentially what I already have. But I would prefer not to have the mechanism for locating and examining attributes in my code base at all, if Ninject has something built-in. If it doesn't, I can live with what I already have.

Comment: I don't know about any built-in possibilities. IMO this few lines of code is completely OK, and for me it doesn't feel like boilerplate. It's descriptive, easy to read (especially the Reflection way). I would refactor the locating logic into a function like `GetArgNameFromType` which would handle the attribute stuff, so that way it would become even cleaner.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis there is nothing pre-built to do exactly what you're looking for.